# How to access to a field value programmatically when field name is variable?

Tags: theming

In my content type I have 4 fields:

- field_talla_s
- field_talla_m
- field_talla_l
- field_talla_xl

That's my code, I just need to change the "m" on field_tallas_***m*** for my variable ***$size*** in case that my size change to S or L or whatever without having to make an if for each size:

```
$size = 's';
print $node->field_tallas_m['und'][0]['value'];
```

How should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your code, you can PHP's curly brace syntax.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
<?php 
$size = 's';
$field_name = 'field_tallas_' . $size;
print $node->{$field_name}['und'][0]['value'];
?>
```

Note that you should be using [`field_get_items`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and/or [`field_view_value`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) instead for best practices.

Comment: Up vote for function suggestions.